# Centering problem with multicolumn in tabular (LaTeX)

Tags: latex, tabular

I want to create a table with two lines to sort details.
The first line will have 3 cells and the second one 2 cells.

For that, I cut the tabular in 6 column, so with multicolumn, by taking 2 column per cell on the first one  and 3 column per cell on the second one.
But the second line is not cener, hwo to do ?
Here's the code :

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Difficulté : Facile} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Durée : 4h} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Coût : 20€} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Niveau : L3} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Eco-Friendly : oui} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. Sometimes table needs fixed columns in order to work.

I slightly changed your code. All the widths specified by `\multicolumn` are factors of a column width `C`, that is 1.5cm, which is defined in preamble. As example, I slightly stretched the first column to compensate for its length:

[image]

Use the factors: `C{2}`, `C{2}`, `C{2}` and then `C{3}`, `C{3}` to get a symmetric table.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\dimexpr1.5cm}}

  
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \centering
  \caption{The table}\label{tab:thetable}\vspace{3pt}
  \begin{tabular}{| *6{C{1}|}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|C{2.4}|}{Difficulté : Facile}
    & \multicolumn{2}{C{1.8}|}{Durée : 4h}
    & \multicolumn{2}{C{1.8}|}{Coût : 20€} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|C{3.3}|}{Niveau : L3}
    & \multicolumn{3}{C{2.7}|}{Eco-Friendly : oui} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```